# PHP autoload is preventing POST

Tags: php, post, composer-php, autoloader

I developed my own PHP classes and used composer to manage all the dependencies between them. But whenever I include "vendor/autoload" on top of any PHP script, the page does not POST. None of the post data from any of the input elements is recognized or received by the script. The following script 'call.php' posts onto itself and nothing happens.

```
try
{
    //------Page url
    $url = 'call';

    //------Set page timeout parameters 
    session_start();    
    if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])  && ((time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout']) > 600)):
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.$url);
        die();  
    endif; 
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

    //------Add required methods and classes
    require dirname(__FILE__).'/../includes/vendor/autoload.php';

    //------Get encrypted user id & device id
    if(isset($_GET['id']) || isset($_GET['device'])):

        //-----Decrypt user id and device id
        $decrypt   = new decryption();
        $user_id   = $decrypt->mc_decrypt($_GET['id']);
        $device_id = $decrypt->mc_decrypt($_GET['device']);

        //-----Validate decrypted data          
        $check     = new validation();
        $c_id      = $check->check_number($user_id    ,'n');
        $c_device  = $check->check_number($device_id  ,'y');

        if($c_id==1 && $c_device==1)
        {
            //-----Create a service object
            $service = new service($user_id);
            $status  = $service->get_user_status();

            //-----Check if the user has a valid status
            if($status != 100)
            {   
                header('Location: logout?logout&message='.$status.'#re101');
                die();
            }
            else
            {
                $user_name = $decrypt->mc_decrypt($service->get_user_name());

                //-----Check for previous service requests
                $details   = $service->get_service_call();

                if($details)
                {
                    $completed = false;

                    if($details['b'] == 'pending' )
                    {
                        $message = '<h2>Your request has been placed...</h2>';
                        $image   = '<h2><img src="images/call_in.png alt="" height="100px" width="300px"/></h2>';

                    }

                    else if($details['b'] == 'processing' )
                    {
                        $message = '<h2>Your request is under process...</h2>'; 
                        $image   = '<h2><img src="images/call_up.png" alt="" height="100px" width="300px"/></h2>';
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $completed = true;
                        $service_id = $details['a'];
                        $message = '<h2>Your request has been fulfilled...</h2>';
                        $image   = '<h2><img src="images/call_out.png" alt="" height="100px" width="300px"/></h2>';
                    }   

                    $dated = $details['c']; 
                }
                else
                {
                    //-----Create a new service request
                    if($service->create_service_call($device_id))
                        echo "Service created";

                    $dated = date('d-m-Y', time()); 
                }
            }
        }

    endif;      

    //-----Once fulfilled, close the service by accepting user rating and feedback
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&!empty($_POST['submit'])):

        $id       = !empty($_POST['service'])?$_POST['service']:'';
        $rating   = !empty($_POST['rate'])?$_POST['rate']:'';
        $feedback = !empty($_POST['feed'])?$_POST['feed']:'';

        $check   = new validation();
        $c_text  = $check->check_textarea($feedback, 'y');

        $feed    = new service(0);

        if(($rating == 10 || $rating == 5 || $rating == 1) && $c_text == 1)
        {
            if($feedback == '')
                $feedback = 'nil';

            if ($feed->give_service_feedback($id, $rating, $feedback))
                $give = 'Thank you for your feedback!';
            else    
                $give = 'Sorry, could not post your feedback.';
        }
        else
            $give = 'Sorry, there was an error.';

    endif;
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    $log = new misc();
    $log->handle_ex($url, $_SESSION['account'], $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
    header('Location: '.SITE.'404.shtml');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Post via ajax

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- button to send form post -->        
<button id="sendforms">Submit forms</button>

        <div id="result"><!-- result of post page goes here --></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#sendforms").click(function() {
                       var combinedFormData = $("#form1").serialize();
                     $.post(
                            "test.php",
                            combinedFormData
                     ).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Successfully submitted!");
                            $("#result").html(data);
                     }).fail(function () {
                              //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                     })
              });
            });
        </script>
```

so all the code post is made in the **test.php** file you can check if is set with php and also return it your form must have a **id="form1"** and don't need

> action="page.php" method="post" please remove this from your form 
>   also the button must be

```
<button id="sendforms">Submit forms</button>
```

If you did't understand I can make a implementation for your you if send all code the form and the php part